# How to remove a device from a ZFS pool?

Tags: linux, zfs, openzfs

I wanted to add `ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H` into the `raidz1-0`. Running `zpool add tank ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H` unfortunately it becomes:

```
$ zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME                                   STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X7NYZ37AS   ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_48HNETHAS   ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_49E8GHPAS   ONLINE       0     0     0
          ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

```
$ sudo zpool remove tank ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H
cannot remove ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H: out of space
```

Actually the whole `ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H` should be free, I think?

```
$ sudo zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  11.8T  7.84T  3.96T        -         -     0%    66%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

May I know how to remove it, and how to add it into the RAID-Z properly?

Thanks.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It seems it is outdated. If not extending RAID-Z, may I know how to remove it from the pool?

Comment: i think you nees to use offlien and detach and after this, remove, maybe https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbbvf/index.html will help you

Comment: @djdomi `$ sudo zpool offline tank ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H` shows `cannot offline ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H: no valid replicas`

Comment: you need to detach it first

Comment: @djdomi `$ sudo zpool detach tank ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H` gives `cannot detach ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H: only applicable to mirror and replacing vdevs`

Comment: could it be that the drive you try to remove is marked as spare?

Comment: @djdomi seems not. According to this page https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gcvcw/index.html spare should be under a `spare-0` level.

Comment: I am cleaning up the `tank` pool to try removing the `device`. Now it gives `cannot remove ata-TOSHIBA_DT02ABA400_90D1S0Q2S75H: invalid config; all top-level vdevs must have the same sector size and not be raidz.`. It seems extending RAIDZ will not be available until late 2022. https://louwrentius.com/zfs-raidz-expansion-is-awesome-but-has-a-small-caveat.html Maybe I will rebuild everything into a MIRROR instead at this moment.

Comment: i would suggest that you take a backup and start from scratch, mostly a raid10 configuration would be fine in most cases

Comment: @djdomi yeah I am backing up everything to cloud and starting from scratch. I will use ZFS-stripe since I have back-up online. Mirror leaves me 50% it is too costly. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: remind, that you need to use wipefs to get rid of ZFS :)